# The parameter doesn't updated throughout optimization

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I want to optimize the parameters vector, gamma, and v using pytorch or tensorflow optimization algorithms like Adam. The code below is my cost function and I want to minimize it with respect to above-mentioned three parameters. Unfortunately, the gamma parameter doesn't change and update at all!
I think it is for utilizing Sign function, because when I change it with softsign or tanh functions, it will get updated. However, is it very essential for me to preserve the precision and strict clustering at point zero, and simultaneously make gamma to update. Could anybody please help me with the problem?

```
def objective_function(self, x):
    nvector = self.vector / torch.norm(self.vector)
    alpha = torch.matmul(x, nvector) + self.gamma
    q1 = torch.sign(alpha)
    yh= q1 * self.v
    error = x - torch.matmul(yh, nvector.T)
    log_error = torch.log2( torch.mean( torch.square( torch.norm(error) ) ) )
    return log_error
```

Comment: I don't think it is mathematically possible.

Comment: How about the best way to implement it with a high similarity function to sign?